# Force .ix to return a DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I use .ix with a DataFrame, is there any way to force pandas to always return a DataFrame?

For example, if I run the following lines,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2), index=[0, 0, 1])
x = df.ix[0]
y = df.ix[1]
```

then x will be a DataFrame, because 0 appears twice in the index, and y will be a Series, because 1 is unique in the index.  I want y to be a DataFrame too (because I'm using iterrows(), which isn't defined for Series, on the result).

I can check the type of whatever .ix returns and convert it to a DataFrame if needed, but I thought there'd be a better way.

**Note**: As of Pandas v0.20, `.ix` [indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in favour of `.iloc` / `.loc`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, index it with a list:

```
> x = df.ix[[0]]
> y = df.ix[[1]]
> type(x)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
> type(y)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```